# On Mac, when installing docker desktop, docker is installed but not the symlinks

Tags: docker

On my Mac (Intel) with Monterey 12.6.5, I downloaded and installed Docker Desktop. The docs say this will install everything. In a terminal window, running 'docker' is an unrecognized command. I don't see docker in the PATH but also, looking in /usr/local/bin I don't see any symlink for docker.

From Docker Desktop I can successfully run containers. I just can't execute the CLI commands. I have reinstalled Docker, no joy.